# 'dist' folders being created for almost every file in my CRA typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I couldn't know the purpose of the 'dist' folders that are being created at multiple places in my project.

[image]

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This was really tricky but I solved it. I was using an extension for vs code known as formatted hero which compiles scss, ts files. It was on so whenever I was writing code it was saving it in the dist folder.

Comment: I had the same issue I fixed it by including `"compile-hero.disable-compile-files-on-did-save-code": true` in my .vscode/settings.json

Comment: Yup I did the same thing